# find -mtime files older than 1 hour

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, cron

I have this command that I run every 24 hours currently.

```
find /var/www/html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I would like to run it every 1 hour and delete files that are older than 1 hour. Is this correct:

```
find /var/www/html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mtime **+0.04** -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I am not sure of my use of the decimal number??

Thanks for any corrections.

### EDIT

OR could I just use **-mmin 60**? Is this correct?

### EDIT2

I tried your test, good thing you suggested it. I got an empty result. I want all files **OLDER** than 60mins to be deleted! How can I do this?? Does my command actually do this?

Comment: If you are using GNU find (and you most likely are) you can also pass the -delete flag instead of the -exec rm business. I think that more clearly expresses the intent.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

What about `-mmin`?

```
find /var/www/html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mmin +59 -type f -name "*.mp3" \
    -exec rm -f {} \;
```

From man find:

```
-mmin n
        File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

Also, **make sure to test this first!**

```
... -exec echo rm -f '{}' \;
          ^^^^ Add the 'echo' so you just see the commands that are going to get
               run instead of actual trying them first.
```

Comment: Wouldn't -mmin 60 only find the files modified exactly 60 minutes ago? I think it needs to be -mmin +59 or such.

Comment: I updated based on Otis' comments.  Nice catch!

Comment: Thanks. :) I'm curious if the modification needs to be 60 minutes or greater or if 59m 1s would trip it. I'm not sure it needs to be that precise for what Abs is doing.

Comment: I'll let you know in 54 minutes and 12 seconds ;-)  Otis++ on a random post of yours

Comment: Ha ha, I'll check back here for an update tomorrow. ;) Thanks for the up vote on the ISO thing.

Comment: instead of -exec rm -f {} \; you can simply use -delete

Comment: **WARNING** [`-exec ... {}` has _command injection vulnerability_. Use `-exec sh -c '... "$1"' - {} \;` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962015/4510033)