# find: missing argument to -exec in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, find

The following works fine when I type it exactly in the command line:

```
find /<some_path>/{epson,epson_laser,epson_inkjet} -iname "*.ppd" 
  -exec grep "\*ModelName\:" {} \; | sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\"/\1/'
```

However, when I try to call the following from a
bash script I get `find: missing argument to -exec'`.

I have also tried the following (in many variants):

```
eval find "$1" -iname "*.ppd" -exec 'bash -c grep "\*ModelName\:" "$1" | sed "s/.*\"\(.*\)\"/\1/" \;
```

as was mentioned in [find-exec-echo-missing-argument-to-exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961673/find-missing-argument-to-exec).
How can I get to work first code not only in terminal, but also in bash script?

**P.S.:** I've used `eval` only for expanding string `"/<some_path>/{epson,epson_laser,epson_inkjet}"` to multiple paths. Does anyone know better solution for doing this?

Comment: That error means that the `\;` argument isn't being seen, but it looks fine to me above. Please paste the exact `find` line from your script.

Comment: Well, doesn't matter which `find` line in script as no one works ;) But how to get the same result as in the first line I typed, but get it to work in bash script? the first line work when I type it directly to terminal, but in bash it in any combination doesn't work.

Comment: When you use `eval` you have to double up the escapes. The first one escapes the character for the original shell, the second one escapes it for `eval`.

Comment: That's why it's better to put the `-exec` command into a script, so you don't need to use `eval`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why you need to use `eval` in the first place.

Comment: Maybe you should also tell us what you're really trying to achieve. We could find the best approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute multiple commands over the output of `find`, just use the `-exec` options as many times required:

```
find -exec command1 "{}" \; -exec command2 "{}" \;
```

You can also define the conditions to execute an option:

```
find \( -exec command1 \; -false -o -exec command2 \; \)
```

In your case, you need something like this:

```
find /<some_path>/{epson,epson_laser,epson_inkjet} -iname "*.ppd" -exec grep "\*ModelName\:" "{}" \;  sed 's/.*\"\(.*\)\"/\1/' "{}" \;
```