# How does `find <path> -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x \{\} \;` work?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I found an old one-line shell script:

```
 find ./../ -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x \{\} \;
```

I understand it grants execution rights on all the shell scripts in the directories below the parent directory. However, I haven't seen the syntax `\{\} \;` before.

I'm guessing the backslashes escape the characters to yield `{} ;`, but what does that mean and why does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\{\}` means substitute the full pathname of the object that has been matched.

The `\;` marks the end of the arguments of the command to be executed.

So

```
-exec chmod +x \{\} \;
```

means run `chmod +x <pathname>` for every `<pathname>` that matches the preceding `find` filtering.  In this case, that will be all files with the suffix `.sh`.

You can read more about `-exec` in the `man` entry for the `find` command.

The backslashes are required because the characters `{`, `}` and `;` all have syntactic significance to the shell.  So you have to tell it that they are literal characters to be passed through to the `find` command.

The pattern `"*.sh"` is quoted for the same reason: to stop the shell itself from doing pathname expansion.

Comment: When `{}` stay together, backslashes are not required in thi sparticular context.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219584/4142984 answer may be interesting if it is "still not working".