# Recursively delete files in directory

Tags: bash

How do I recursively delete files in directory that were modified more than 6 hours ago?

This example work for 1 day:

```
find /data2/input -type f -mtime +1 -delete -print
```

Comment: See: [-mtime FIles older than 1 hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543946/mtime-files-older-than-1-hour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-mmin` instead of `mtime`. It will allow you to specify the number of minutes since the files was last modified. So for files older than 6 hours:

```
find /data2/input -type f -mmin +360 -delete -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the flags `-cmin` or `-mmin` in the manual page.